# Problema al tratar de generar Excel en php con phpspreadsheet MVC

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, phpspreadsheet

resulta que hace tiempo estoy tratando de solucionar un problema, que estoy un 75% seguro que son dos script de JS.
El aplicativo está hecho en PHP con MVC (ningún framework).

copio mockup para mayor entendimiento:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Actualmente tengo un diseño parecido al mockup, el cual tiene 2 divs, el primero muestra el menú, cada opción tiene una link que llama al controlador y al metodo desde la vista.

```
<a href="acción/tabla" class="cargar" name="objeto">acción 2</a>
```

el trabajo del primer Javascript es que cuando el cliente haga click en cualquier hipervinculo, busque la ruta (controlador - metodo) y lo "pinte" en el div "objeto" (parte derecha) sin recargar la página.

**JS # 1**

```
<script>
jQuery(function($){
    $(document).on('click','a', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var $target = $(event.currentTarget);
        var destinationLocation = $target.attr('href');
        if (destinationLocation !== '#') {
            $('#objeto').load(
                destinationLocation
            );
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Despues de eso, me enfrete a otro problema y es que si había alguna acción como un submit, dentro del controlador - metodo llamado anteriormente, ese no funcionaba sin recargar la página y siguiera en el mismo div "objeto",eso lo solucioné con el siguiente JS.

**JS # 2**

```
<script>
        $(function(){
            $("#excel").unbind().submit(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                let data  = $("#excel").serialize();
                EnviarExcel(data);
            });
        });

        function EnviarExcel(data){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'excel/descargar',
                data: data,
                success: function(data)
                {
                    $('#objeto').html(data);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

Pero ahí viene mi siguiente problema y es por el cuál estoy haciendo está pregunta, ese JS funciona para comunicarme, llamar, llevar datos etc, sin que se pierda el manejo dentro del div, pero al momento de generar un excel, con phpspreadsheet, no descarga nada y alcontrario me imprime caracteres raros en el div.

envío controlador:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;

class excel extends Controlador
{

    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    public function descargar(){

        $documento = new Spreadsheet();
        $documento
            ->getProperties()
            ->setCreator("aquí se crea")
            ->setLastModifiedBy('Parzibyte') // última vez modificado por
            ->setTitle('excel')
            ->setSubject('prueba')
            ->setDescription('excel de prueba')
            ->setKeywords('etiqueta')
            ->setCategory('para php');

        $nombreDelDocumento = "excel.xlsx"; 

        header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="' . $nombreDelDocumento . '"');
        header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

        $writer = IOFactory::createWriter($documento, 'Xlsx');
        $writer->save('php://output');
        exit;
    }
}
```

**HTML**

Es el form dónde lleva los datos de la tabla de la vista al controlador, y crear el excel.

```
<div class="col-6">
            <form id="excel" method="post" autocomplete="off">
                <textarea name="excelmovimiento" id="excelmovimiento" rows="10" cols="100" hidden="hidden"><?php
                    echo json_encode($cierre_movimiento);
                    ?>
                </textarea>
                <textarea name="exceltotal" id="exceltotal" rows="10" cols="100" hidden="hidden"><?php
                    echo json_encode($cierre_saldo_total);
                    ?>
                </textarea>
                    <div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Excel </button>
                    </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Pero no sé porqué me sale esto :(

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]